# Inter Vlan Packet Transfer

Tags: routing, vlan, layer2, layer3

I am trying to establish communication between 2 devices within different vlan. But I require a router for that. Can I send packets within different VLAN without having a router or a Layer 3 device.

Comment: The whole entire reason for the existence of, and point of using, VLANs is to separate layer-2 traffic.  If devices can't talk at layer-2, they need to communicate at a higher layer (layer-3) and the device to do that is a router.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

No you can't.  If you forward packets at layer 2 between the two VLANs, you have effectively made them into one VLAN.  If you forward packets based on layer 3 information,well, that is the definition of  router.